# Debuggin app with VS I get not a valid32 application

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-hosted-app, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to deploy my first app on Sharepoint online with visual studio 2015.

[image: I get the error you see in picture]

I have tried setting platform target x86 but it makes no difference.
Do you know what the problem is?

**EDIT:**
prefer32 is grayed out:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the Platform target to Any CPU and uncheck the prefer 32 bit option.

[image]

Comment: unfortunately it's grayed out and I can't understand how to make it flaggable.